# Collapsing animation effect not working (dissolving instead) - Fiddle inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want the last two rows of the table in the fiddle to be hidden and stretch up with an animation when clicking on "see more". I've managed to get this far with the code - [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnc6152p/)

But the animation is dissolving instead of stretching. 
what should I add (preferably with minimum code) to get such an effect?

**Also, HTML, CSS, and Jquery-wise, is the whole code in general the best practice in this case?**

for example, should I apply the `.hidden` class to the `tr`?

I've tried wrapping these two rows in one DIV and apply the .hidden class to it, but it didn't work.

CSS:

```
.clk {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.clk:hover {
    color:#903;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

table, tr, td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <table border="1">
    <col style="width:115px;" />
    <col style="width:125px;" />
    <col style="width:145px;" />
    <col style="width:125px;" />
    <col style="width:190px;" />
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="clk">See More</span></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clk').click(function(){
        $('.hidden').toggle(700)
    });
})
```

Comment: What do you want? There is no stretch with toggle, it only toggles hide/show. You could use slideToggle and set your speed lower that 700ms. The "dissolve" effect you are seeing is because you having it happen over 700ms, try a lower speed.

Comment: @Macsupport lower speed makes it pop right up, with no transition at all, I've tried slideToggle, it was also without transition...

Comment: @Macsupport I'm not necessarily looking to use these functions, if there's another transition functions I would be happy to know about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `slideToggle` a table row, it doesn't work well. What I did was enclosing each `td` content in a div, and `slideToggle`'ing each of those divs. Be aware that this should be a bit slow depending on the number of cells and the client computer.

```
$('.clk').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').toggle(700) // Fade the rows
    $('.hidden td div').slideToggle(700) // Slide the contents
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fzmuyp0u/

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if there's still a better solution, since while testing this, I've noticed that it makes the content of the cells to stretch, but the cells themselves are not reacting very simultaneously so it looks a bit lagged

Comment: [I've made some changes to your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fzmuyp0u/1/), when the cells have some padding inside it seems like the animation would work ok without adding any DIVs, what do you think?

Comment: this makes the animation more clear, but you can see that the text itself appear at once, and also the table look too big. you could also replace the whole table by div's.